Mongoqueryable Join query taking longer time
 public async Task<PaginationResult<TypeEntity>> GetAllWorkFlowAsync(string filterCondition,string sort, int page, uint? limit, bool includeDeleted, string model)
 {
     var sharedResult = _mongoRepository
    .GetAllAsync(SharedDbQueryableCollection.Where(td => model == null || td.Model == model).ApplyFilter(filterCondition, _scopeConditionEnforcement));

     var tenantResult = _mongoRepository
     .GetAllAsync(TenantDbQueryableCollection.Where(td => model == null || td.Model == model).ShouldIncludeDeleted(includeDeleted)
     .ApplyFilter(filterCondition, _scopeConditionEnforcement));

     var result = (await Task.WhenAll(sharedResult, tenantResult))
         .SelectMany(t => t).ToList();

      var finalResult = result
         .Join(WorkFlowDbQueryableCollection,
             main => main.Id,
             workflow => workflow.Id,
             (main, workflow) => new TypeEntity(main.TypeId, main.Version.ToString())
             {
                 Id = main.Id,
                 Model = main.Model,
                 Body = main.Body,
                 Version = main.Version,
                 WorkFlowStatus = workflow.Body
             })
         .ToList();
     var paginationInput = MongoQueryableExtension.CreatePaginationInput<TypeDefinitionEntity>(sort, page, limit);
     var paginatedResult = PaginateTypeDefinition<TypeDefinitionEntity>(finalResult, paginationInput);

     return paginatedResult;

 }

Above is the code for an API which combines the result from multiple collections on Id match. This API is taking 13 sec and by using timestamp I came to know that this part is taking more time.
Any suggestions how can i reduce response time.
